TypeError: ADAM.minimize() got an unexpected keyword argument 'initial_point'
When I run the below code, it shows the below error. I tried with COBYLA and still same,
    optimizer = ADAM(maxiter=100)
    
    new_params = optimizer.minimize(len(agent.params), objective, initial_point=agent.params)


However, when I change the code as below,
    while True:
        action = int(agent.choose_action(state))
        new_state, reward, done = env.step(action)

        # Quantum reinforcement learning update
        def objective(params):
            q_circ = q_circuit(params, state + action)
            q_circ_transpiled = transpile(q_circ, agent.backend)
            q_job = assemble(q_circ_transpiled, shots=1000)
            job_result = agent.backend.run(q_job).result()
            counts = job_result.get_counts(q_circ_transpiled)
            return -counts.get(str(action), 0)

        print("agent.params: ", agent.params)
        new_params, _, _ = optimizer.minimize(objective, agent.params, jac=None, bounds=None)

Here, agent.params:  [0.43454172 0.87378962]
Nonetheless, It shows the below error,

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated. Thanks

The parameters to minimize are all positional.  You need to delete the string initial_point=.  However, the documentation shows the parameters in a different order.  https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/qiskit/0.26/qiskit.algorithms.optimizers.ADAM#qiskit.algorithms.optimizers.ADAM.minimize

If I remove it still gives another error, , TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

I believe you have confused minimize and optimize.  minimize accepts three parameters: the objective function, an initial point, and a gradient function.  It does not want the length.

The above link is pretty old - here is the latest docs https://qiskit-community.github.io/qiskit-algorithms/stubs/qiskit_algorithms.optimizers.ADAM.html#qiskit_algorithms.optimizers.ADAM.minimize
minimize(fun, x0, jac=None, bounds=None)
where fun is the objective function (callable) and x0 will be the initial point.

Hi @SteveWood, I have updated the information on the post. It still has errors which I don't know why.

Try casting the return from the objective function to a float. This is what the callable signature states and ADAM has some check against the return type where its looking for a float and if not enters that code you show.
